# python pattern match and process

Tags: python, regex, text

i am trying to parse log with bunch of lines.
The line i am trying to parse from live  trace (kind of tail from file) is the one that starts with "Contact".
Actually i need to use everything between brackets whatever is within 
[2a00:c30:7141:230:1066:4f46:7243:a6d2] and number separated by double dots after brackets (56791)
as variables.
I have tried wit regex search but i do not know how to deal with.

```
Contact: "200" <sip:200@[2a00:c30:7141:230:1066:4f46:7243:a6d2]:56791;transport=udp;registering_acc=example_com>;expires=600
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the format is always the same:

```
for line in logfile:
    if "Contact" in line:

        myIPAddress=line.split('[')[1].split(']')[0]
        myPort=line.split(']:')[1].split(';')[0]
```

Answer (score 0):

use regex to do so

```
import re
logfile = open('xxx.log')
p = r'\[([a-f0-9:]+)\]:([0-9]+)'
pattern = re.compile(p)
for line in logfile:
    if line.startswith('Contact:'):
        print pattern.search(line).groups()
logfile.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

If you getting new entries through something like `tail -f $logfile`, you can pipe the output of that to this:

```
import re
import sys

for line in sys.stdin:
    m = re.match(r'Contact: .*?\[(.*?)\]:(\d+)', line)
    if m is not None:
        address, port = m.groups()
        print address, port
```

Basically reads each line that comes in on standard input and tryes to find the items you are interested in. If a line does not match, then shows nothing.

Comment: Thx. I just adopted this to fit my need. Helped me out and give me ideas

Answer (score 0):

```
    data =re.search(r'Contact: .*?\[(.*?)\]:(\d+)', line_in_file)
    if match: 
       temp=line_in_file.split('[')
       temp1=temp[1].split(';') 
       hexValues = re.findall('[a-f0-9]', temp1[0])
```

Comment: find the line, parse the line and get "[......]:...;" this of the line ,take all the values

Comment: Thx ceasif. I solved my problem and you guys help me giving solutions and ideas. Thx a lot

Comment: @user1627588 Feel free to tick the answer if it seems halpful :P